Can the if-keyword be used to modify a definition in JSON schema?
I've got a data structure I'm attempting to write a JSON Schema for, where many elements contain strings translated into one or more languages, here's a minimal example with English and French:
{
  "supportedLanguages": ["en", "fr"],
  "serviceName": {
    "en": "My App",
    "fr": "Mon Application"
  },
  "customerSupportEmail": {
    "en": "help@myapp.com"
  }
}

If I want to specify conditions, using JSON schema, so that "if English appears in supportedLanguages, every translated string (object with one key per language) must contain an English. I can do that per property, like this:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "example",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "supportedLanguages": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["en", "fr", "de"]
      },
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "serviceName": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "en": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "fr": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "de": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "customerSupportEmail": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "en": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "fr": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "de": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "supportedLanguages": {
            "type": "array",
            "contains": {
              "const": "en"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "serviceName": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["en"]
          },
          "customerSupportEmail": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["en"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
   (... others, one per supported language, ommitted to make this snippet shorter)
  ]
}

This example works correctly, failing validation when a supportedLanguage value is present which is not the key for one of the fields.
Ideally I'd like to split the logic into a definition ($def), so it can be reused between many properties.
I tried doing it as follows:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "example",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "supportedLanguages": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["en", "fr", "de"]
      },
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "serviceName": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/translatedString"
    },
    "customerSupportEmail": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/translatedString"
    }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "translatedString": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "en": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "fr": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "de": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "supportedLanguages": {
            "type": "array",
            "contains": {
              "const": "en"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "$defs": {
          "translatedString": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["en"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    (... skipped the other languages again)
  ]
}

but, testing with ajv in Node, this does not work.
Is there a way to add conditions to the definition inside the if-then-else structure?

You can modularize everything into $defs. here's an example of yours
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "example",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "supportedLanguages": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["en","fr","de"]
            },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "serviceName": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/lang_kvType"
        },
        "customerSupportEmail": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/lang_kvType"
        }
    },
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/english_lang"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/french_lang"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/german_lang"
        }
    ],
    "$defs": {
        "lang_kvType": {
            "title": "Language Key Value Pair",
            "propertyNames": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/CountryCodeType"
            },
            "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "CountryCodeType": {
            "title": "CountryCodeType",
            "description": "The 2 character country code. As per ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2",
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 2,
            "minLength": 2
        },
        "english_lang": {
            "if": {
                "required": [
                    "supportedLanguages"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "supportedLanguages": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "contains": {
                            "const": "en"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "serviceName": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "en"
                        ]
                    },
                    "customerSupportEmail": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "en"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "french_lang": {
            "if": {
                "required": [
                    "supportedLanguages"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "supportedLanguages": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "contains": {
                            "const": "fr"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "serviceName": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "fr"
                        ]
                    },
                    "customerSupportEmail": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "fr"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "german_lang": {
            "if": {
                "required": [
                    "supportedLanguages"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "supportedLanguages": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "contains": {
                            "const": "de"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "serviceName": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "de"
                        ]
                    },
                    "customerSupportEmail": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "de"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


EDIT, if you want to use enumerations for the country attribute names you can do this
This will constrain the naming to only the enumerations provided, rather than a 2 character string value which I previously defined as CountryCodeType.
 "$defs": {
        "lang_kvType": {
            "title": "Language Key Value Pair",
            "propertyNames": {
                "enum": ["ar", "ab", "ac", "en", "fr", "de"....]
            },
            "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }


Thanks for the detailed example. Inside english_lang, french_lang etc, the names of the other fields are enumerated - serviceName, customerSupportEmail - I was trying to ask whether this can be done without repeating these names every time, like in my (non-working) example. Does this answer mean that it's not possible?

are the enumerated property names the country codes?  that's the reason I used the lang_kvType which constrains the property names to 2 characters and type: string.  if you wanted to enumerate those values, you can change the CountryCodeType schema to have an enumeration of all the countries rather than a 2 character string.  checked the edit.

I'm sorry that I'm not being very clear here. I'm totally new to JSON Schema, so probably using the terms incorrectly. My wish, if it's possible, is to avoid repeating serviceName and customerSupportEmail inside every if-then, so that more of these (I think they're the properties) can be added without updating many different places. In my example, I tried to modify the translatedString def inside the if-then, but that doesn't seem to make the key required inside the places that reference the def.

ah ok., you just want to reduce the repetition in the if, then statements. With each of them being a different const and required values, I think you're at the limit of modularizing this schema with the two options I gave you

That's a shame, but thanks for the help!
